# Data Corruption issue running function in Tomcat 5.5 & 6.0

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos

I've been trying to figure out this bug for few days.  I have narrowed the issue down to a test case as follows.  Again, this is a test case that causes the bug to happen.  The function (at this point) is not a practical one, but just trying to figure out the bug.

Server is running:
 - Tomcat 6
 - OpenJDK 1.6.0_17
 - CentOS 5.5

I have a simple Class file with the following method Static Method and Static variable declaration:

```
public static java.text.SimpleDateFormat displayDateSDF1 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

public static java.util.Date getSubDateMini(String inputDate)
{
    java.util.Date testObj = null;
    try
    {
        testObj = displayDateSDF1.parse("01/01/2000") ;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return testObj;
}
```

**Testing in Tomcat:**

When I run this method, I'd expect to get the same result every time, right?  However, if I call this method from a JSP, I get the expected result of a Date object with value 1/1/2000 about 99.9% of the time.  However, sometimes I get an unexpected data object passed back with a seemingly random date value.

To test this, I created a JSP with the following code segment in it:

```
for (int i=0; i<200000;i++)
{
    java.util.Date testObjLib = TestDate.getSubDateMini("") ;
    if (testObjLib!=null&&!testObjLib.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2000"))
    {
            out.print("<br>"+testObjLib+"");
    }
}
```

Some dates that appear are as follows:

**Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 1**

**Fri Aug 01 00:00:00 PDT 2166**

In 200,000 runs, I get approximately 50 bad dates which gives an error rate of ~0.025% but again it's random.  I've run this loop with 10 iterations and received an error.  Sometimes it runs the loop with 200,000 and all dates look good.

**Testing in Java:**

Running this loop via a console/terminal app in CentOS with the same loop, I have not seen this error happen yet.  I increased the loop to 10,000,000 and had no false results as of yet.

---

I can understand out of memory or some thrown error (which would result in a null value) but not corrupt/inconsistent data.   I built up a new server from scratch with Tomcat 6 and also tried Tomcat 5.5 and both have the same results.  I have not tried Tomcat 7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the Sun bug database for bug no [4264153](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4264153). SimpleDateFormat and related format classes are not threadsafe.

Comment: I've read some issues about SimpleDateFormat not being Thread safe from several years ago. Is that still the issue here?  By declaring it as a static variable is that causing data corruption that seems only apparent in Tomcat?

Comment: @Vineet   The link you mention says it was resolved in version 1.4.  I'm on version 1.6.   Is this still an issue in Java?  Maybe their Fix was simply to notate it as not Thread Safe?

Comment: The documentation was updated. I don't think the DateFormat classes were changed to make them threadsafe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe.

This means that when it is accessed from multiple threads, unexpected results can be observed. And tomcat is serving each request from a separate thread, so whenever two requests are made at the same time, the problem would arise.

You have a number of options:

- instantiate the `SimpleDateFormat` on each call of the method (rather than making it `static`)
- if you need the format more than once per thread, use a `ThreadLocal` to store it.
- alternatively use joda-time, where `DateTimeFormat` is thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks - I think this resolves the issue.  We use JODA in other functions, but not in this method so that should be an easy transition.

Comment: Just to clarify:  Does this mean I just need to make it a new variable instance once within the function or every time I call .parse?  For example, is it okay to do:  testObj = displayDateSDF1.parse("01/01/2000") ; testObj2 = displayDateSDF1.parse("01/02/2000") ;  one after the other in the same code block?  Assuming the declaration of displayDateSDF1 is done locally in the function and not static.